# Tem como apagar ImageButton

Tags: android

Estou criando vários `ImageButton`

```
 ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.imagebutton, null);
            imageButton.setImageBitmap(bMap);

            layoutC.addView(imageButton);
```

Queria saber se tem como remover-los do layout.

Comment: imageButton.setVisible(View.'unvisible..') serve?

Comment: acho que não porque acho que vai chegar uma hora que vai ter muitos repetidos la

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você terá de informar um ID para cada `ImageButton`.

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.imagebutton, null);
imageButton.setImageBitmap(bMap);
imageButton.setID(id_do_seu_imageButton);

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) layoutC.findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_imageButton);
((LinearLayout) imageButton.getParent()).removeView(imageButton);
```

Comment: mais ai pega todos os imagebutton que tem no layout

Comment: Pra isso você informa um id para cada `ImageButton` ou armazena todos eles num array

Comment: eu colocando o id em cada um , como eu pego ele?

Comment: atualizei a resposta, outra forma seria usando Maps que seria quase a mesma forma. Como você gera esses buttons e como você os remove? depende do fluxo do seu programa....

Comment: Eu to gerando eles depois que eu pego da internet as imagens deles , ai tava fazendo no onResume , mais to pensando um lugar melhor ou ate um jeito melhor de criar eles pra nao ter que apagar , só inserir os que faltam , pq tipo se atualizar na internet quantos botões são ai inserir só os novos se ja tiver algum criado deixar eles, eu iria apagar tudo para criar e não compensa

Comment: Antony só pra não criar outra pergunta , quando crio um botão la no xml posso colocar onClick para criar um método para ser chamado com ele e clicado , como faço isso desse jeito que to criando?

Comment: Use `imageButton.setOnClickListener(...)`